# AWS S3 CLI ACL public-read gives me 403 with sync command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, aws-cli

I can't figure out why I get a 403 permission denied error when viewing a page. I am using AWS CLI with the following command:

```
aws s3 sync [source] [s3 destination] --acl public-read --recursive --delete --profile [my_profile]
```

On IAM my policy is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
  "Resource": ["bucket_location"]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:PutObjectAcl",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
      "Resource": ["bucket_location"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The paths are correct since it does upload the files but it looks like it's ignoring the --acl public-read option. When i use cp command, it looks like it's running okay. I just like to use sync to use the --delete option for clean up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In your second policy statement (the one with `PutObject,...`), be sure to include a wildcard character for your object names:

```
"Resources" : [ "bucket_name/*" ]
```

Do you know you can test your policies using the online [Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/iam-policy-simulator-guide.html) tool?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's what I found thanks to @sebsto suggesting the Policy Simulator: I need both `PutObjectAcl` and `PutBucketAcl`. Now sync works.